# How to customozation loading ui android?

Tags: android, user-interface, loading

this is the normal loading "image" is shown in android
[image]

I want to customization for example change it to ..

[image]
or 
[image]

how do we replace the first loading for them? do we need pics? or some xml file?

Answer (score 0):

res/layout.xml

```
 <ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" >
      </ProgressBar>



drawable/progress.xml This is a custom ProgressBar that i use to change the default colors.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- 
    Duration = 1 means that one rotation will be done in 1 second. leave it.
    If you want to speed up the rotation, increase duration value. 
    in example 1080 shows three times faster revolution. 
    make the value multiply of 360, or the ring animates clunky 
-->
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@color/color_preloader_center"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="@color/color_preloader_end"
            android:startColor="@color/color_preloader_start"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```